# SSAS and Excel PivotTable -- apply dimension to only one set of values

Tags: excel, excel-2010, ssas, pivot-table

Using a common Calendar Hierarchy, I'm trying to generate a pivottable that has a dimension applied to only one data set. I might not be explaining this properly;

So I capture the flow rates of 3 separate meters, called unimaginatively 1,2 & 3. I have a fact table with these values, I have a meter dimension, and I can pull them into a table without issue. I also have a target value. It's a single number for all meters. Is it possible to have a the 'meter' dimension applied against the flow rate, and then have target as a standalone value without the meter dimension applied against it?

Is this possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the following calculated measure in your cube to get your measure "target" independent from the "meter" dimension:

`(Root([name of meter dimension]), [Measures].[name of target measure])`

See here for info about the root function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146076.aspx